How to pull predictions from a set of overlapping normal curves
I have a problem writing a program that is beyond my stats level that I need help with.
I have a set of pupil heights in a school, divided into 4 sets of class data. Each set of class heights can be fitted into a normal curve producing mean, variance, and class size for each class.
What I need to do is given a pupil of height x, predict the probability of them being in each class.
I am trying to produce a formula with the four variables to produce a probability for each class that will add up to 100% for all 4 classes.
Any pointers much apprediated
Edit as requested -
Class A pupil heights follow a normal distribution described by mean = 1500; standard deviation = 120; class size = 32
Class B: Mean = 1400; standard deviation = 100; class size = 27
if pupil X has a height of 1430 what is the probability that they are in Class A given that they are in either A or B

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
